# Mongoose virtual return null

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongoose, mongoose-schema

I have a Person schema :

```
const person = new mongoose.Schema({
    name: String,
    birthday: Date,
    sex: String
},
{
    toObject: { virtuals: true },
    toJSON: { virtuals: true }
});

person.virtual('tasks', {
    ref: 'task',
    localField: '_id',
    foreignField: 'person'
});

export default mongoose.model('person', person);
```

And a task one which has the `person` field :

```
const schema = new mongoose.Schema({

    person: {
        type: mongoose.Schema.Types.ObjectId,
        ref: 'person',
        required: true
    },

    name: String
});

export default mongoose.model('task', schema);
```

And my API to retrieve one person :

```
api.get('/person/:id', async (req, res) => {
    let personID = req.params.id;

    if (personID) {
        let person = await Person.findById(personID);

        if (person)
            res.json(person);
        else
            res.status(404).end();
    }
    else {
        res.status(400).end();
    }
});
```

When I query the API for one person, `tasks` is always `null`, any ideas why?

Thanks

**Update**

I tried with :

```
let person = await Person.findById(personID).populate('tasks').exec();
```

and it's still returning `null`.

Comment: don't you need to populate `task` like this `Person.findById(personID).populate('task')` to get `task` data.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ok I found the issue, I was registering the model before setting up the virtual (in some wrapper I wrote around mongoose.Schema).

Answer (score 2):

> Use `populate` in your query.

**Can you please check one of the below query**

```
let person = await Person.findOne({ _id: personID })
  .populate('tasks')
  .exec((error, personData)
    => personData);
```

OR

```
let person = await Person.findById(personID)
  .populate('tasks')
  .exec((error, personData) => personData);
```

> reference Link : http://thecodebarbarian.com/mongoose-virtual-populate